# TYPO3 Backend - Search first_name of fe_users

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

following my TCA:

```
'fe_user' => [
        'exclude' => 0,
        'label' => 'FE-Users',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'group',
            'internal_type' => 'db',
            'allowed' => 'fe_users',
            'foreign_table' => 'fe_users',
            'size' => 1,
            'minitems' => 0,
            'maxitems' => 1
        ],
    ],
```

When I click on "Website User" in the backend, I can search for the FE users. Is there a way to search for their first names? If yes how?

Comment: This type of field should automatically add a search field right next to the select field. Did you try to search there or do you want a search function inside the popup after clicking on "Website User"?

Answer (score 2):

You need 'additionalSearchFields'. Something like:

```
[...]
'config' => [
    [...]
    'suggestOptions' => [
        'default' => [
            'additionalSearchFields' => 'name,first_name,last_name,middle_name,address,telephone,fax,email,title,zip,city,country,company,description'
        ]
    ]
]
```

Edit the list of additionalSearchFields to include just the fields you want to search, such as `first_name`.

> **additionalSearchFields (string)**
>   Comma-separated list of fields the suggest wizard should also search in. By default the wizard looks only in the fields listed in the label and label_alt of TCA ctrl properties.

Reference: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/ColumnsConfig/Type/Group.html?highlight=additionalsearchfields#suggestoptions

This 'suggestOptions' for type=group was [added in TYPO3 8.6](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/latest/Changelog/8.6/Deprecation-79440-TcaChanges.html?highlight=suggestoptions#suggest-wizard) in place of the suggest wizard.